# Change table row background color on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve some kind of half transparent color overlay over hover on a table row, I created a little [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d3xx2zxw/) here.

However I don't want the text to be altered in any way, so just the background, and the reason I want it to be kind of a overlay is that I just want the cells to be slightly darker and not the same color on hover. Make sense?

code:

```
<table id="compTable" class="prTable">
    <tr class="prTableHeader">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prTableRow">
        <td class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Squat</td>
        <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td>
        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.prTableCell {
    padding: 7px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    cursor:default;
}

.prExerVariNameTD {
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1!important;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.prVerticalSpace {
    width: 50px;
}

.rowHover {
    /*background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);*/
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table#compTable .prTableCell:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
    $("table#compTable .prTableCell:odd").css("background-color", "White");

    $(".prTableRow").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("rowHover");
    });
});
```

Comment: Just use CSS: `.prTableRow:nth-child(even):hover { background-color: #eee; } .prTableRow:nth-child(odd):hover { background-color: #fff; } `

Comment: Your title and your code are a little different here. You say you want to change the row background color on hover, but then your code has set the background colors of table cells.

Comment: ye when I first tried it only changed the cell I was hovering, and then it was all just a mess :/ @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JavaScript. CSS to the rescue!

This sets the background colors slightly darker on hover. You can play with the actual color values to make the colors darker or lighter on hover.

```css
.prTableCell {
  padding: 7px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  cursor: default;
}

.prExerVariNameTD {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1!important;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.prVerticalSpace {
  width: 50px;
}

.prTableCell:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.prTableCell:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.prTableRow:hover .prTableCell:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.prTableRow:hover .prTableCell:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table id="compTable" class="prTable">
  <tr class="prTableHeader">
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="prTableRow">
    <td class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Squat</td>
    <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td>
    <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
    <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
    <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that you could make it target only the current cell by moving the `:hover` from the table row to the cell.

Comment: this is great! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you were very close with your `rgba` background(except that you were targeting the row and not the cells). Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table#compTable .prTableCell:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
    $("table#compTable .prTableCell:odd").css("background-color", "White");

    $(".prTableRow").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("rowHover");
    });
});
```

```css
.prTableCell {
    padding: 7px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    cursor:default;
}

.prExerVariNameTD {
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1!important;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.prVerticalSpace {
    width: 50px;
}

.rowHover td:not(.prVerticalSpace) {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="compTable" class="prTable">
    <tr class="prTableHeader">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prTableRow">
        <td class="prExerVariNameTD blackColor">Squat</td>
        <td class="prVerticalSpace"></td>
        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
        <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ah cool, is it possible to incorporate even/odd in here so that all of them dont end up the same color? but rather just a tad darker than original so that they still look different from each other?

Answer (score 0):

annswer at https://jsfiddle.net/v9jphr5h/

```
tr:nth-child(2n) 
{
  background-color:#ffe;
}

tr:nth-child(n+2):hover>td,
tr:nth-child(n+2):hover>td.prTableCell[title]{
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5)
}
```

bottom line:
 - your rgba-approach works
 - absolutely no need for jquery
 - (unless you want to compatible with the oldest browsers, but in that case, you can't use rgba eithter. In that case, figure out the colors for every cell and add "odd" and "even" classes to the rows.)